Merge two JSON files with jq, adding integers
I have two JSON files of the form:
{
    "xFruits": {
        "views": 163,
        "all": {
            "xApples": {
                "views": 28,
                "eats": 10,
                "discards": 17
            }
        }
    },
    "xVegetables": {
        "views": 134,
        "all": {
            "xBeans": {
                "views": 29,
                "eats": 11,
                "discards": 14
            },
            "xCarrots": {
                "views": 30,
                "eats": 12,
                "discards": 11
            },
        }
    },
}

Keys starting with x change names and vary in number. The others are fixed. Most x keys exist in both files, but some may exist only in file 1 and others only in file 2.
I want to use jq to merge both files and add numbers when have the same path. So if this is the second file:
{
    "xFruits": {
        "views": 16,
        "all": {
            "xApples": {
                "views": 2,
                "eats": 2,
                "discards": 5
            }
        }
    },
    "xVegetables": {
        "views": 147,
        "all": {
            "xBeans": {
                "views": 12,
                "eats": 7,
                "discards": 13
            },
            "xSpinach": {
                "views": 30,
                "eats": 12,
                "discards": 11
            },
        }
    },
}

The the mix of both would result in:
{
    "xFruits": {
        "views": 179,
        "all": {
            "xApples": {
                "views": 30,
                "eats": 12,
                "discards": 22
            }
        }
    },
    "xVegetables": {
        "views": 281,
        "all": {
            "xBeans": {
                "views": 41,
                "eats": 18,
                "discards": 27
            },
            "xCarrots": {
                "views": 30,
                "eats": 12,
                "discards": 11
            },
            "xSpinach": {
                "views": 30,
                "eats": 12,
                "discards": 11
            },
        }
    },
}

Note how xCarrots and xSpinach retained their original values because each only existed in one file, while all other values were added together.
Is this something jq is capable of?

This question is similar to: How to merge 2 JSON objects from 2 files using jq?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, the question is different, and I think it’s pretty clear how: this asks about adding integers and not just merging values blindly.

You could iterate over a stream of path-value arrays using tostream and reduce, and successively build up the result object using getpath, setpath and simple addition. Initially non-existent paths evaluate to null, which for the addition acts as 0.
jq -n '
  reduce (inputs | tostream | select(has(1))) as [$p,$v]
    (null; setpath($p; getpath($p) + $v))
' file1.json file2.json

{
  "xFruits": {
    "views": 179,
    "all": {
      "xApples": {
        "views": 30,
        "eats": 12,
        "discards": 22
      }
    }
  },
  "xVegetables": {
    "views": 281,
    "all": {
      "xBeans": {
        "views": 41,
        "eats": 18,
        "discards": 27
      },
      "xCarrots": {
        "views": 30,
        "eats": 12,
        "discards": 11
      },
      "xSpinach": {
        "views": 30,
        "eats": 12,
        "discards": 11
      }
    }
  }
}

Demo

@user137369 I've compiled a walk-through demo with some simplified sample data. Tell me if any of the steps is still unclear.
